# General questions of curiosity

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Would it be appropriate to post a message in stackoverflow asking about specific resources one might recommend for learning/tutorials or even game-related methods to learn a subject? (or, is that out of bounds or off-topic?)

Comment: No, that's not really suited to a Q&A site. From the help page: *"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."* How to learn something, or requesting resources wouldn't constitute a question about a problem that you face, it's a discussion / poll / resource request post, not an actual question.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I assumed this to be the case, but I thought I would throw it out there. Where might one go (similar to SO) to answer such questions? Any ideas?

Comment: Google for "X forum" where X is the topic you wish to ask about. Chances are you'll get a lot of hits regardless of the topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. No. No.

Resource questions are entirely off-topic, not just on Stack Overflow, but essentially all of the network.

We call them shopping questions, see the [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) blog post about them.

Comment: Thank you for the blog post. I figured there must be something out there that particularly addresses this.